# Google Cloud Platform Static Website SLL issue

Tags: ssl, web, google-cloud-platform, dns

I purchased a domain via third party recently and I am trying to host my website on Google Cloud Storage, I have a few issues which I cannot find any solutions for.

1) I bought an SSL cert via my domain provider and now am trying to attach it to my bare domain. I also have my buckets for bare domain, www domain, and a subdomain. I have added my SSL to App Engine but nothing comes out of it.

Here are my buckets:
[Buckets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L145.png)

Here is my DNS setting: [DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hVKG.png)

And here are my custom domains on GCP App Engine: [Custom Domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jmvv.png)

I initially had a URL re-direct to www.shivnpatel.com but then changed it to the IPV4 provided. Also, the SSL security for bare domain was my SSL cert which I bought from my domain provider. I had to change that to Google managed so I could attach it a bucket as I was told by my domain provider (I had a bucket for shivnpatel.com but deleted it because nothing was being fixed...).

Anyway, after changing my DNS to add an A record, my site started giving me 404 errors. So how should I fix this mess?

2) my subdomains, www.shivnpatel.com and resume.shivnpatel.com have an error next to them (as show in the 3rd image above) saying

> DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically.

How can I fix this? How can I give my subdomains SSL?

Also, since all of this is Google managed, is adding SSL necessary? And lastly, would anyone recommend using Cloudflare and providing my site using it to get out of this mess?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have your domain, by following your approach, first you need to [map your custom domain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_your_app) on GCP, then [update your DNS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update) records with your registrar (I believe you are missing this step, check [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#troubleshooting_managed_ssl_certificates) for more detailed information).

You can use your own certificate or use a Google Managed one in App Engine, if you still want to use your own follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#using_your_own_ssl_certificates) steps (in the same page you can find the instructions if you decide to use Google Managed Certificates instead, but it doesn't support Wildcard Mappings).

There are some other options if you just want to use buckets:

1. The simplest scenario is if you are planning to host only [static
   websites](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website), you can manage or [add subdomains](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-subdomain) too.
2. Use a [Bucket as backend](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets) for a Load Balancer, but this adds
   complexity, it depends on your needs.